# XPath - XML document nodes selection problem

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, saxparser

Need help with XPATH.

I use this library [jcabi](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-xml) (see [samples](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/04/24/java-xml-parsing-and-traversing.html)) to process XML document. I'm facing a problem (all nodes named "member" are retrived, I just want the first level of "member" nodes not the nested ones.

```java
    XML myXml = new XMLDocument(stringXMLFormat);
    List<XML> members = myXml.xpath("//struct/*"); // the problem is "//stuct/*" I can't find appropriate expression to query only first level of member nodes.

    Instead having members.size() = 4, I have members.size() = 6.
    
    I dont want the two nested member (Member Level 2)
    
    <struct>     +------------------------------------
         <member>| Exclude this part from the result
                 <struct>
                 |     <member>
                 +------------------------------------
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>   <!-- NOT THIS : I apply XPATH query on this :   myXml.xpath("//struct/*") ==> Retrieve all member nodes in the document; but I just want the firs level of member nodes --> 
                    <member> <!-- Member -> Level 1 : Must be retrive --> 
                        <name>attribut1</name>
                        <value>
                            <int>0</int>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member> <!--Member -> Level 1 : Must be retrive --> 
                        <name>attribut2</name>
                        <value>
                            <struct>
                                <member> <!-- Member Level 2 : I don't want to retrive this --> 
                                    <name>attribut2-attr1</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <boolean>1</boolean>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                            </struct>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member> <!--Member -> Level 1 : Must be retrive --> 
                        <name>attribut3</name>
                        <value>
                            <array>
                                <data>
                                    <value>
                                        <struct> <!--NOT THIS --> 
                                            <member> <!--Member -> Level 2 : I don't want to retrive this --> 
                                                <name>attiribut3-attr-1</name>
                                                <value>
                                                    <int>1</int>
                                                </value>
                                            </member>
                                        </struct>
                                    </value>
                                </data>
                            </array>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member> <!-- Member -> Level 1 : Must be retrive --> 
                        <name>attribut4</name> 
                        <value>
                            <string>10</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

How can I select just the **first level of member** *WITHOUT* **selected all member in the document** ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please let me know if my solution resolved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//member[not(ancestor::member)]
```

will select all `member` elements that do not have `member` element ancestors.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes, it's works. I voted for your answer because you did not only give the correct path but also give the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
"//struct/*"
```

Use

```
"//param/value/struct/*"
```

**UPD**
Explanations:
You are simply selecting all the elements below `struct` tagged element while my expression will select all the elements below `//param/value/struct`.
That means:
Find `param` element directly followed by `value` directly followed by `struct`. Now find all the elements below this node.
This will select only relevant `member` nodes since there are inner `member` nodes as well but they are sitting below this nodes sequence: `//data/value/struct`.
The second solution here given by kjhughes is good as well.

Comment: Thanks @Prophet, It works. But don't understand what it means.

Comment: @aristos I have added the explanation

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it's help to understand.